# WCF - Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled

Tags: 2016, metadata, topology, service

I'm trying to clear up the Events Viewer in my UAT environment, and one of the errors I'm getting is Event 8313.

```
A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure
Process Name: w3wp
Process ID: 4136
AppDomain Name: /LM/W3SVC/1299132374/ROOT-1-131878147433506875
AppDomain ID: 2
...
```

It came up with a link the MetadataWebService.scv (`http://<Server>:<Port>/740c9be36e4c4762b1beedfca16f92fd/MetadataWebService.svc`) stating that

```
This is a Windows© Communication Foundation service. 
Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.
```

It says in order to fix the issue I should...

1. Add `<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />` to the service behaviour configuration
2. Add the behaviourConfiguration attribute to the Service tag if it doesn't exist yet (already existed)
3. And add the endpoint (`<endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />`) to the service.

So that the web.config for the service looked similar CODE-BLOCK 1, below. The Config file I edited now looks like the one in CODE-BLOCK 2.

**As far as I can tell, done as the page said, but I still get the error. Can someone help me figure out a solution?**

#### CODE-BLOCK 1

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>

        <services>
            <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
            <service name="MyNamespace.MyServiceType" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
                <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
                <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
                <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
            </service>
        </services>

        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors" >
                    <!-- Add the following element to your service behavior configuration. -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

#### CODE-BLOCK 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTopologyWebServiceApplication" behaviorConfiguration="TopologyServiceTypeBehavior" >
          <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="TopologyWebServiceHttpBinding" contract="Microsoft.SharePoint.ITopologyWebServiceApplication" />
          <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="TopologyServiceTypeBehavior" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="TopologyWebServiceHttpBinding">
          <security authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport" />
          <textMessageEncoding>
            <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="2097152"/>
          </textMessageEncoding>
          <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="1073741824" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This may as well be some breaking change in the runtime, gone unnoticed. I am facing the exact same issue for a newly minted WCF service in a brand new environment. Following the instructions in the given link doesn't change anything, my configuration file looks very similar to yours except the naming differences.